# Formatting the values of an array to be fitted within a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary, append

How can I set the numpy array `a` into three list sets within the dictionary `dictionary` as `one, two, three` just like the expected output below?

Code:

```
import numpy as np 
set_names = np.array(['one', 'two', 'three'])
a = np.array([12,4,2,45,6,7,2,4,5,6,12,4])
dictionary = {}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    'one': [12,4,2,45],
    'two': [6,7,2,4],
    'three': [5,6,12,4]
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the *slicing* operator for lists and arrays? Do you need this to work for this example only, or are you looking for a more generic way to slice an array into three equal parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.array_split`:

```
>>> dict(zip(set_names, np.array_split(a, len(set_names))))
{'one': array([12,  4,  2, 45]), 'two': array([6, 7, 2, 4]), 'three': array([ 5,  6, 12,  4])}
>>>
```

As lists:

```
>>> {k: list(v) for k, v in zip(set_names, np.array_split(a, len(set_names)))}
{'one': [12, 4, 2, 45], 'two': [6, 7, 2, 4], 'three': [5, 6, 12, 4]}
>>>
```

Comment: what if the results of every `one` and `two` was every nth digit like the output. Example for every 3rd digit `{'one': array([12,  45,  2,  6]), 'two': array([4, 6, 4, 12]), 'three': array([ 2,  7,  5,  4])}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this approach with `reshape`.

```py
import numpy as np

names = np.array(["one", "two", "three"])
a = np.array([12, 4, 2, 45, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 6, 12, 4])
```

```py
dictionary = {}
for i, name in enumerate(names):
    dictionary[name] = list(a.reshape(len(names), -1)[i])

print(dictionary)
```

This gives the following output.

```py
{'one': [12, 4, 2, 45], 'two': [6, 7, 2, 4], 'three': [5, 6, 12, 4]}
```

---

Or if you want a one-liner, here is the equivalent dict comprehension for it.

```py
print({name: list(a.reshape(len(names), -1)[i]) for i, name in enumerate(names)})
```

This gives the following output.

```py
{'one': [12, 4, 2, 45], 'two': [6, 7, 2, 4], 'three': [5, 6, 12, 4]}
```